# New-AzureStorageContainer : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden in powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-storage-emulator

**The problem**

I am getting started with azure blob storage so followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) to get started. I am trying to connect to a storage emulator locally and I am using Powershell to try and create a new container but when I use the following script

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "devstoreaccount1" -StorageAccountKey "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
New-AzureStorageContainer "sascontainer" -Permission Off -Context $context
$now = Get-Date
New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name "sascontainer" -Permission rwdl -ExpiryTime $now.AddHours(-1.0) -Context $context -FullUri
```

I get this message:

> New-AzureStorageContainer : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: Server failed to authenticate the request. 
>   Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

**What I have done**

- checked the azureStorageEmulator.exe.config

`<accounts>
          <account name="devstoreaccount1" authKey="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" />
        </accounts>`

- a bit of searching returned [this](http://irisclasson.com/2014/05/23/set-azurestorageblobcontent-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden/) which caused me to check the time my emulator is set to (to do that I called `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/sascontainer`). The responce was an error but this shows the emulator is set to UTC time which is 1 hour behind my computers time, which I have allowed for in my script
- Download Microsoft Azure storage explorer and connected successfully through that tool. I tried to look fins something useful in this tool to help me, but was unable to do so

**The question**
How do I connect to the azure storage emulator via powershell

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you? If so, you could accept it or if you have further questions, just ask.

Comment: Hi, this question is part of an ongoing side project which I will be working on again soon. I will let you know once I have tried it

Answer (score 0):

To access storage emulator, we can use `New-AzureStorageContext -Local` 
or `New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`.

With more details, we can also set `-ConnectionString` with

```
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;"
```

Specifying only StorageAccountName and StorageAccountKey like you have done is to visit `http://devstoreaccount1.blob.core.windows.net` online. Because by default the service endpoint is `<http|https>://<account-name>.<service-name>.core.windows.net`, while in local development it's `http://127.0.0.1:1000<0-2>/devstoreaccount1`. See the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#addressing-resources-in-the-storage-emulator) you mentioned.

And reference of [powershell document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext?view=azurermps-6.1.0#examples).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found the solution in your description of the problem.
All I needed for that is to adjust time (turn off and then on automatic time adjustment).

In my case the same PowerShell script, what worked yesterday stopped working today.
What have changed? In fact, I've just rebooted my laptop and logged into my ubuntu account and than rebooted back to windows. It shifts time for several hours. I know of this bug, but usually I do not care of it much.
But while working with online services it could lead to authentication problems like that.